# What loses its head in the morning / and gets it back by night?

Tags: riddle

Another strange riddle:

> What loses its head in the morning
>
> And gets it back by night?

What is the answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an old one (although I'm not sure if it's appeared here before).

The answer is

> A pillow

Comment: What if the dude in question sleeps a siesta?

Comment: @CrazyCoding I think the answer still works in that case given the phrasing of the riddle.